# i want to join two ffmpeg command to gather

Tags: merge, ffmpeg, command

This command is for add video in to video :

> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i over.mp4 -filter_complex
>   "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=224x400[top];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=100x44[bottom];[top][bottom]overlay=x=115:y=346:eof_action=pass;[0]volume=0.7[a1];[1]volume=0.3[a2];[a1][a2]amix=inputs=2[a]"
>   -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 -map 0:v -map "[a]" out.mp4

This command is for add water mark and username text in to video :

> ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex
>   "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-15,drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:text=‘@Unknown':
>   fontcolor=white: fontsize=10: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.0: boxborderw=5:
>   x=160: y=380" -codec:a copy output.mp4

If i want to execute this two command together then what i have to do OR how can i join this two command in one ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the watermark and drawtext after the overlay.

`ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i over.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=224x400[top];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=100x44[bottom];[top][bottom]overlay=x=115:y=346:eof_action=pass[vid];[vid][2]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:main_h-overlay_h-15,drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:text=‘@Unknown': fontcolor=white: fontsize=10: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.0: boxborderw=5: x=160: y=380;[0]volume=0.7[a1];[1]volume=0.3[a2];[a1][a2]amix=inputs=2" -acodec aac -vcodec libx264 out.mp4`

Comment: Error :
Output with label 'a' does not exist in any defined filter graph, or was already used elsewhere.